# Invalid Authentication Data. Connection refused. Cann't login github from android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am trying to push my android app project to GitHub account. for this, while I'm trying login my Github account it shows me the error message:
"Invalid Authentication data. Connection refused. connect"
what is the solution to that problem? In the image I entered my GitHub username and password but it shows the error described above without login.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a token instead of your credentials.

Log in to github in your browser. Go to
[Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)

Generate new token. Make sure you grant access to following scopes: repo, gist, read:org

Copy your token back to Android Studio and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Search for HTTP Proxy in the idea settings, and remove the proxy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I changed my [ proxy software ] before. This is exactly where the error occurred. After fixing the port, it worked fine.